# Using a negative loop number in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, counter

I have a for loop, using `i` as the counter, in Excel VBA.  I have one statement that stubbornly gives me errors:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLookup(RC[-3],R3C7:R22C15,3)" & " & " & "R[-i]C" & " _ 

& " & "Vlookup(RC[-3],R3C7:R22C15,4)"
```

Using the `-i` is evidently causing the errors.  I tried adding 
`negi=-i` and then changing the `R[-i]C` to `R[negi]C`, but that didn't fix it. I added a Dim negi as Integer statement in earlier code.

Edit:  Here's more of the code.  I'm using two loops.  rownumber is the counter for the outer loop, and i is the counter for the inner loop.  i ranges from 1 to 20, and rownumber ranges until a row is reached with a blank in column 3.

```
Range("A25").Select
Dim Rownumber As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim negi As Integer
Rownumber = 1
```

' This starts the outer loop
    Do While ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3) <> ""
' Adds twenty rows
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

```
Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(19, 5)).Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown

ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
```

For i = 1 To 20

```
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = i
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
 ActiveCell.Value = Rownumber
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Vlookup(RC[-2],R3C7:R22C15,2)"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    negi = -i
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLookup(RC[-3],R3C7:R22C15,3)" & " & " & _
     "R[negi]C" & " & "& "Vlookup(RC[-3],R3C7:R22C15,4)"

    ....
    rownumber = rownumber + 1
    next i
```

How can I accomplish this while avoiding errors?

Comment: What is the value of i when it gives you an erro? What is the error? Is it possible that the cell you're changing is, say, A1, and you are telling it to go to A0 [which does not exist]?

Comment: Provide complete code sample you're using. We can't read in your mind or direct from your screen.

Comment: Edited to add more code in response to comments.

Comment: @Grade 'Eh" Bacon - the value of i is 1 when I get the error.  The error I get is Run time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of bad string concatenations in the formula build.

`i` will have to be outside of the quoted string(s) and concatenated in and `& " & " &` probably isn;t doing what you want it to.

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-3],R3C7:R22C15,3)&" & _
                                   """ & ""&R[-" & i & "]C&"" & ""&" & _
                                   "VLOOKUP(RC[-3],R3C7:R22C15,4)"
```

Remember that you have to double up quotes within a quoted string.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a loop from a greater value to a lower value. This will loop from the last cell used to the first.

```
lRow = ws.UsedRange.Rows.count
Do While lRow > 0
    lCol = ws.UsedRange.Columns.count
    Do While lCol > 0
        If InStr(ws.Cells(lRow, lCol), job) Then

        End If
        lCol = lCol - 1
    Loop

    lRow = lRow - 1
    ws.Range("A" & lRow).Activate
Loop
```

Comment: Thanks, Matthew.  But the issue isn't just the sign of the argument in the  "R[negi]C" statement.  I replaced the "negi" with simply "i" and it still failed.  But when I replaced "negi" with "-1', it worked.  I suspect the issue is simply with getting the RC format to accept a variable.